# Loop sql result to display rows without duplicating using php

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables. product_data contains all the details about the product and product_images which has all the images for each product. I joined both the tables but the problem is that some products have more than 2 images. so the product rows duplicate

```
product_name  | description | ucode |  star_rating | product_image

cheese            packed       321        3            1.jpg
cheese            packed       321        3            1.jpg
cheese            packed       321        3            3.jpg
meat              canned       F98        1            meat1.jpg
milk              canned       G43        5            milk1.jpg
milk              canned       G43        5            milk2.jpg
milk              canned       G43        5            milk3.jpg
milk              canned       G43        5            milk4.jpg
```

When I have a foreach loop

```
 foreach ($products as $product):
    //display the product details once and all the images for that product
    endforeach;
```

The output will be like,

```
product 1          1.jpg
                   2.jpg
                   3.jpg
product 2          meat1.jpg
product 3          milk1.jpg
                   milk2.jpg
                   milk3.jpg
                   milk4.jpg
```

I want to list all the products along with the images. How can I display the product details only 1 time and all the images for that product and move to the next product? There's is a maximum of 6 images for a product

The SQL query - 3 tables have been joined

```
SELECT *
FROM product_data p
LEFT JOIN product_img_map im ON im.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_images i ON i.photo_id = im.photo_id
```

Comment: Can you show us the SQL query?

Comment: @HydraIO i have added the sql code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it all in an array:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    ....
    $product_array[$product_name]['images'][] = $product_image;
    ....
}
```

then you will have more control over your output by looping through the product array you created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT `product_data`.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(`product_data`.`product_image`) as Pictures
FROM `product_data`
GROUP BY `product_data`.`product_name`
```

You will get a new row `Pictures` containing all images separated by comma.

Comment: actually there 3 tables joined basically 1 table is used to map the product id with image id. i have added the sql code. Is it possible to use the concat with my sql code?